# Ubuntu 16.04 - Purge php completely but still shows PHP 5.4.15 (cli)

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php5, ubuntu-16.04

I want to purge PHP completely from my Ubuntu 16.04. I have did all the stuff to remove PHP which as below,

```
sudo apt-get purge "php*"
sudo apt-get purge "^php.*"
sudo apt-get purge "^php*"
sudo apt-get remove "php*"
sudo aptitude remove ~iphp
sudo aptitude search "~iphp"
rm -rf /etc/php/
```

Although when I check from the terminal and run `php -v` it still shows the PHP 5.4.15 (cli).

Does have any idea about this?

Comment: Can you share the output of `dpkg --list | grep php`?

Comment: Hi Shunz
It gives me nothing.

Comment: Maybe it was not installed via package manager? Try `which php` and `whereis php` to show the full path of the `php` binary.

Comment: which php shows "/usr/local/bin/php"
whereis php shows "php: /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/lib/php /usr/local/php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, looks like `php` was installed either via *source code* or with some kind of binary distribution, but *not* via `apt`/`dpkg`.

To uninstall it, you should first know *how* it was installed!

Usually, if via source code, you should find a directory under `/usr/src` or `/usr/local/src` (or your `home`, or...) containing the said source code (maybe `/usr/src/php-X.Y.Z`).

Then it (usually!) will be enough to use `make uninstall`, but you should check the source code documentation for the proper procedure.

If it was installed via a binary distribution, there *might* be an **uninstall** command (try looking in `/usr/local/bin`) or you should proceed to manually delete every file/directory.

If you didn't install `php` yourself, you should ask *who* installed it which method was used and acting accordingly.

**EDIT as per comments**

Looks like you installed it via source code, so to uninstall it you can try

```
cd php-5.4.15
make uninstall
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install gcc libmysqlclient-dev libxml2-dev
wget --trust-server-names http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.4.15.tar.bz2
tar xjf php-5.4.15.tar.bz2
cd php-5.4.15
#./configure --prefix=$PWD/installdir --enable-bcmath --with-mysql
./configure
sudo make install
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade

Comment: I have been followed this link
https://myonecent.wordpress.com/2016/11/29/install-php-5-4-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Do you mean 
"make uninstall" is a command to uninstall it?

Comment: I tried with cd php-5.4.15 and then run sudo make uninstall
Then I get "make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop."

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. unfortunately, if there's an uninstall target, there isn't an automated way to remove files. You should go and delete installed components manually. Start looking into `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc.